# Move cursor SetCursorPosition

Tags: c, winapi, cursor

I want to move my mouse on my screen, I use this code :

```
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, int *argv[]){
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    printf("Current cursor position (%d, %d)\n", pt.x, pt.y);
    pt.x = 100;
    pt.y = 100;
    SetCursorPos(pt.x, pt.y);
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    printf("Current cursor position (%d, %d)\n", pt.x, pt.y);
    system("pause");
 }
```

This script works I see that the position changes, but the mouse does not move on the screen. Should I use another function to move cursor ?

Comment: What was the return value from each of those 2 cursor functions?

Comment: Really ? you cursor move on the screen ? @machine_1

Comment: Win8.1, VS2013. The cursor doesn't move.

Comment: Win7 Ult. VS2010 . The cursor move.

Comment: Win8.1, VS2013. The cursor move

Comment: Hum me I use Win7 and VS2015 Comunity

Comment: The same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/q/22259936/2564301?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you confuzzle the cursor of a console mode program with the mouse cursor.  Use SetConsoleCursorPosition() instead.

Comment: Yes I use console mode program but I want move the mouse cursor, I have already seen the function `SetConsoleCursorPosition()` but this function is for move cursor on the console, and me I want move the cursor on the screen

Comment: @simon : Debug or Release build?

Comment: @sjasm : Release build why?

Comment: @ Could you try in the debug mode and see if the cursor moves?

Comment: @sjasm : No change with debug mode the cursor don't move. it's really strange, I get the position is correct but the visual is not good the cursor don't moves

Comment: If I use the keyboard to move the mouse it works and I use `SetCursorPos()` so why if I use `SetCursorPos()` without keyboard the cursor dont't move it's so strange

Comment: @simon : No means of seeing the return values in the debug mode?

Comment: @sjsam : `SetCursorPos()` return BOOL and in my case this BOOL is True. If if I make a `mouse_event()` after `SetCursorPos()` to simulate right click I see that the position is good. It's really a visual problem, the cursor does not move

Comment: Are you connected to your development machine through a virtualization software, like Remote Desktop or Citrix Receiver?

Comment: Yes this is virtualization and I think that's problematic, because if I'm on a machine "normal" my cursor move. And for this I use `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y)`. This function operates on "normal" machine but It doesn't work virtualized machines (VMware)