# program stops running when going to task manager

Tags: python, windows

I have a program which makes the mouse go crazy and point randomly on different places on screen.
it works just fine, but when i go to task manager or simply click ctrl + alt + delete, it stops functioning, even when im exiting task manager. 
any help?

(the program still seems to run in the proccess list, but simply doesn't do anything)

the program:

```
from win32api import SetCursorPos,GetSystemMetrics
from time import sleep
from random import uniform
from win32console import GetConsoleWindow
from win32gui import ShowWindow

win = GetConsoleWindow()
ShowWindow(win,0)

def click(x,y):
    SetCursorPos((x,y))

while True:
    click((int)(uniform(GetSystemMetrics(0),10)),(int)(uniform(GetSystemMetrics(1),10)))
     sleep(0.02)
```

Comment: Is it a self written program, or something you downloaded? Please provide more context

Comment: self written. edited and added the program now

Comment: [C++ move mouse in windows using SetCursorPos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259936/c-move-mouse-in-windows-using-setcursorpos)